# How to create lookup field programmatically using AddFieldAsXml Method in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have two lists(Invoice & Client) which i had created dynamically through code and i want to create lookup field programmatically for relationship between this two list.
In Invoice List i have following columns:
1.ID
2.InvoiceNo
3.ClientId - this column i need to create as lookup
4.ClientId:ClientName - this column is used to get ClientName from Client List when i enter ID in ClientId Column
5.etc

In Client List i have following columns:
1.ID
2.ClientName
3.Address
4.etc

So far i'm able to create lookfield that is ClientId in invoice list 3rd column but how can i create programmatically 4th column has additional column.

When we create lookup column using sharepoint administration there is an option called "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" this i want to create programmatically

**My Code**

```
List refList= webobj.Lists.GetByTitle(Constants.Client);
clientContext.Load(refList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Field LookUpField = listObj.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
"<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='ClientId' Required='FALSE' List='" + refList.Id + "' 
ShowField='ID' StaticName='ClientId' 
Name='ClientId' />", true,AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
LookUpField.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks